# Relationship with three columns Laravel Roles, Teams and Projects

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

i have a team, project, user, role, permissions relationship in laravel.

User can have many teams, a team can have many projects and user can have User role, team role and project role. How can i get the user permissions for every project, every team and for user only? Let me show you the tables to explain better.

**User table**

- Id
- name
- current_project_id
- current_team_id
- role_id
- etc

**Teams table**

- id
- name

**Projects table**

- id
- name
- description

**Roles table**

- id
- name
- type(user,project,team)

**Permissions table**

- id
- name

**Role_permission table**

- permission_id
- role_id

**project_user table**

- project_id
- user_id
- role_id

**team_user table**

- team_id
- user_id
- role_id

The user only can have 1 role for 1 project, 1 role for 1 team and 1 role for user, it should be admin or user.

I'm trying to get the user project roles like that, also i've skipped the teams code, because i think that is very similar to projects code.

```
class User extends Authenticatable
{
    public function projectRole()
    {
        //I can't find the way to insert project_id like in where, because current_project_id is null in boot
        return $this->belongsToMany(Role::class, 'project_user')->where('project_id', '=', $this->current_project_id)->first();
    }

    public function projectPermissions()
    {
        return $this->projectRole()->permissions;
    }

    public function permissions()
    {
        //I can't find the way to get all team permission, project permissions and user permissions
    }

    public function role() : BelongsTo
    {
        //Only can be User role, Admin or Support
        return $this->belongsTo(Role::class);
    }

    public function userPermissions()
    {
        return $this->role->permissions;
    }
}

class Role extends Model
{
    public function permissions()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Permission::class);
    }
}
```

I want to use permissions as a gate, to pass to inertia front end, i'm trying something like that

```
Gate::before(function ($user, $permission) {
            return $user->projectPermissions($user->currentProject)->contains($permission) || $user->teamPermissions($user->currentTeam)->contains($permission) || $user->teamPermissions($user->currentTeam)->contains($permission)
            || $user->userPermissions()->contains($permission);
        });
```

Comment: Laravel does not support ternary relationships. You will probably need to convert your `project_user` and `team_user` tables into models rather than pivot tables (i.e. put an `id` in there as well and create models for them).

Comment: @apokryfos thanks for answer, so do you refer that I need to get the project_user model and after get role or something like that? $projectUser->role?

Comment: If you want to go down the complicated route you'd have a `ProjectUser` model related to `Project`, `User` and `Role`. Then you could do `$user->userProjects` to get all user projects. However in your case if the permission is either user or admin there's no real reason you'd need a separate table and you can instead use an enum for the permission (which removes the need to have the ternary relationship and use [this](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/eloquent-relationships#retrieving-intermediate-table-columns))

Comment: @apokryfos i think that i don't explain better. Exists three types of roles, all belongs to the user. But 1 is for the user in project, 1 is for user in general and 1 is for user in team. The user general role is Admin, Support or User. The team role could be "Team Manager" "Team Member", "Team Admin" and project roles could be "Project Manager", etc. So i need that user only have 1 and only 1 role for every category and get the permissions for every category like "user projectRole and user project permissions", "User Team role and User team permissions" and "User role and user permissions"

Answer (score 0):

according to your explanation, I acted in this way:

Tables *************

project_user Table:

```
Schema::create('project_user', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->unsignedBigInteger('project_id');
    $table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id');
});
```

permission_role Table:

```
Schema::create('permission_role', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->unsignedBigInteger('permission_id');
    $table->unsignedBigInteger('role_id');
});
```

role_user Table:

```
Schema::create('role_user', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->unsignedBigInteger('role_id');
    $table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id');
});
```

Models *************

User model:

```
/**
 * Team Relationship
 *
 * @return BelongsToMany
 */
public function teams(): BelongsToMany
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Team::class);
}

/**
 * Project Relationship
 *
 * @return BelongsToMany
 */
public function projects(): BelongsToMany
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Project::class);
}

/**
 * Role Relationship
 *
 * @return BelongsToMany
 */
public function roles(): BelongsToMany
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Role::class, 'role_user');
}
```

Team model:

```
/**
 * User Relationship
 *
 * @return BelongsToMany
 */
public function users(): BelongsToMany
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(User::class);
}

/**
 * Project Relationship
 *
 * @return HasMany
 */
public function projects(): HasMany
{
    return $this->hasMany(Project::class);
}
```

Project model:

```
/**
 * Team Relation
 *
 * @return BelongsTo
 */
public function team(): BelongsTo
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Team::class);
}

/**
 * User Relation
 *
 * @return BelongsToMany
 */
public function users(): BelongsToMany
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(User::class);
}
```

Role Model:

```
/**
 * Permission Relation
 *
 * @return BelongsToMany
 */
public function permissions(): BelongsToMany
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Permission::class, 'permission_role');
}

/**
 * User Relation
 * 
 * @return BelongsToMany
 */
public function users(): BelongsToMany
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(User::class,'role_user');
}
```

Permission Model:

```
/**
 * Role Relation
 *
 * @return BelongsToMany
 */
public function roles(): BelongsToMany
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Role::class, 'permission_role');
}
```

First, we create our desired roles. for example:

### role 1:
name = Super Admin,
type = user

### role 2:
name = Team Supervisor,
type = team

### role 3:
name = Project Developer,
type = project

4 .
5 .
6 And as many roles as you want.

Now we assign desired roles to our users. These roles are stored in the role_user table.

Then, based on these roles, you can determine the duties of each user in each project and team.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Alireza, that’s correct, but the user can have role in project and also in the team, is for that that project_user table has role id. Also team _user has role_id column, tht I try to figure out Is how  to get only 1 records in project_user with permissions for current project or the role for current project, because user only can have 1 role for 1 project, and 1 role for 1 team.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried [Spatie Permissions Library](https://spatie.be/docs/laravel-permission/v5/introduction), it may allow you to create different roles that work with middleware.

Once installed you can do stuff like this in controllers/models:

```
// Adding permissions to a user
$user->givePermissionTo('edit articles');

// Adding permissions via a role
$user->assignRole('writer');

$role->givePermissionTo('edit articles');
```

And in Laravel Gate:

```
$user->can('edit articles');
```

Further to that you can use the Teams Permission feature:
https://spatie.be/docs/laravel-permission/v5/basic-usage/teams-permissions, that you can extend for Projects or Teams.